# php command line maximum process

Tags: php, multiprocessing, command-line-interface

I run many times PHP script in one minute in my server using command line. but i want to add some maximum for it.

this script not must be run each time more than 10 process for PHP.

```
#1 php -r myhardandlongprocess.php
#2 php -r myhardandlongprocess.php
..
#10 php -r myhardandlongprocess.php
```

any standard way for this?

Comment: @fdomig: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110644/comment-regarding-accept-rate-removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command to do that:

```
$output;
$return;
exec('ps |grep ' . __FILE__ . ' |wc -l', $output, $return);

echo ((int) trim($output[0])) - 1;
```

**EDIT:** Changed to `exec()` since `system()` outputs everything directly.